# Javascript date object

Tags: javascript, date, object

I am instantiating a Javascript Date object in my script using the setFullYear, setMonth,....methods in the Date object. But the resulting Date object shows the year and month as 1+. For example if I set the year to 2012 and month to 12. The Date object would show up as 2013, January....

How can I avoid this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Month is zero-based. You should set 11 for December.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth

Comment: I'll +1 this if you remove the link to w3schools and replace with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth  w3schools is renowned for misinformation/errors

Comment: and there's your +1. Seriously, have a look at the last link I posted.

Comment: @LeeTaylor, thanks for the link. I am not aware of that previously. w3schools always come up top in Google's search result page. So I thought the information in their site is reliable.

Comment: No worries. The worrying this is that many people probably believe they're reliable too. Also, Mozilla's documentation is well regarded.